# Show a random mysql row, but not the same twice

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a database that holds all my information with questions, users, answers etc.

I've been thinking all day how to solve this problem of mine. Okey, so the problem is like this:
Let's say I have a table in my DB, with questions (300++) and the user that logs on will get a random question shown. But never the same question again, so I'll need to store this information in a separate table with the user-ID and the question-ID. And I'll need to create another table that stores the answers to the questions.

So how would this PHP/MYSQL-code look like? Because I'll need to find a random question that hasnt been shown to the same user again.

If something is unclear, please let me know. And thanks in advance

Comment: Why downvote? Can't find any duplicate or any answers.

Comment: I agree with you. I think that they are undeserved.

Comment: Why is it important to choose a random question? Why can't you just start each user at the beginning (lowest id number) and go up? Then all you need to store is the highest question id the user has seen.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall': That is simpler and after method of course. But I was thinking that it would mix thing up a bit and also see new methods :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `RAND()` function and `NOT IN`

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM `questions` WHERE id NOT IN (5, 3) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
```

You have to fetch question id using sub query

Example

```
SELECT * FROM `questions` WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT question_id FROM shown_questions WHERE user_id=1) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Nice, this will give me alot of help! Im going to read up on NOT IN function. Did not know about that one! :)

Comment: It's extremely slow on large worksets: for each row, you need to test every value in the set.

Comment: Yeah, I figured. But this will maybe be the best method? To achieve this problem.

Comment: @zneak Yes it will be slow.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an outer join to select items that have not been used already. It might be a bit faster than NOT IN if you set up the indexes:

```
SELECT questions.* FROM questions
  LEFT JOIN shown_questions
         ON (questions.id=show_questions.question AND user_id=42)
 WHERE shown_questions.question IS NULL
 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Nice, thanks! I'll do some testing and compare the load time :)